# forceChatter:feed and forceChatter:publisher are not available in LWC?

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning-web-components, lightning-experience, lightning-community

**forceChatter:publisher** and **forceChatter:feed** , these components are not available in lwc.

Please suggest if there are any similar components are available in lightning web components.

Comment: Any updates on when these will be available in LWC?

Comment: Please provide updates on this.